# Getting DNS error for curl localhost:8080

Tags: http, go, networking, dns, centos

I'm trying to create a http server in go, when I run the code, I'm getting the output as

**Listening on localhost:8080**

But when I use **curl localhost:8080** to test it I'm getting DNS error

The below code starts an HTTP server, listens on port 8080 incoming requests.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
) 

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
    })

    log.Println("Listening on localhost:8080")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

This is the output I get when I run **curl localhost:8080**

```
$ curl localhost:8080
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Looks like its an DNS issue, I'm trying to setup the http server in a VM, how can I fix this error?

Comment: I think you might find your answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/245156/how-can-i-connect-to-a-web-server-running-in-a-vm-when-the-vm-is-in-nat-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One guess is your http request is going through a proxy. You can unset the `HTTP_PROXY` variable and try again.

Otherwise, try using `127.0.0.1` or the IP address for your machine. `:8080` means the HTTP server is binding to all IPs.